# emacs philosophy: add dwim behavior when pressing Enter

Tags: hooks, customize

I recently added a modification to my Enter keybinding based on an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22107501/set-emacs-to-smart-auto-line-after-a-parentheses-pair/22109370#22109370) (if you can't see it, this is a link) on this SE. It was good and I liked it. So of course...

Now I want to add MORE dwim behavior. Specifically, while programming, if I'm typing a comment, I'd like to press the Enter key and the next line automatically also be a comment. E.g. in Ruby, if I have `# blah blah|` where `|` is the cursor, I want to press Enter and see

```
# blah blah
# |
```

So the question - what is preferred / philosophically correct with emacs?

Do I:

1. Expand my `enter-key-dwim` function to just check for more things?
2. Do I switch to two small functions that work as a local-buffer `post-command-hook` and only run if the last command was the Enter key?
3. Put an advice around the Enter key behavior?
4. Something else?

One comment says that I generally want to avoid `post-command-hook` because it gets run after every keystroke as well, which seems to be a vote against option 2.

Comment: Could you please clarify what you'd like to do?  Please also reframe the question to make it a little more concrete.  "Philosophically correct" will probably elicit a lot of opinion-based answers, which don't fit well with the SE format and which we try to avoid.

Comment: FWIW, a useful rule of thumb is to avoid `post-command-hook` if you reasonably can.  Anything in that hook will run after every single command you enter.  Doing so is probably going to be overkill, and depending on what you're asking Emacs to do, could be a big performance issue as well.

Comment: Out of curiosity could you say what your current `enter-key-dwim` does? Maybe just edit a link to the Emacs SE answer you mentioned into your question...

Comment: @OmarAntolín-Camarena Done

Comment: @Dan sounds like I shouldn't use option 2.

Comment: @Dan Explained exactly what I want to have happen. I don't think it modifies my question, since I know I can accomplish this in at least two ways; I want to know which is the preferred way in emacs.

Comment: I think `M-j` (`indent-new-comment-line`) already does this.

Comment: @npostavs That simplifies my life a little. I want this to be part of my enter-key-dwim ... And since I suspect I may add more things to the enter key, I'd like this code to remain readable as it expands.

Comment: Not all modes use `indent-new-comment-line` for that functionality, however. Some bind `M-j` to a custom variant. See also http://stackoverflow.com/a/9060267

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just make your own hook! Here's an example that does what the answer you linked does: add an extra newline if you are between brackets. You can add other hooks without changing `newline-dwim`.

```
(defun newline-dwim ()
  (interactive)
  (run-hooks 'newline-hooks))

(defun basic-newline ()
  (newline)
  (indent-for-tab-command))

(defun extra-newline-inside-braces ()
  (when (and (eq ?\( (char-syntax (char-before)))
             (eq ?\) (char-syntax (char-after))))
    (save-excursion (basic-newline))))

(add-hook 'newline-hooks #'basic-newline)
(add-hook 'newline-hooks #'extra-newline-inside-braces)
```

Comment: I love it. I don't know why I didn't think of it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Behavior of several commands is customizable. The features in question often are called "electric". python-mode.el would provide that comment-insert when `py-electric-comment-p` is set to `t`.

Comment: Thanks. I guess my problem is that I want this for every mode that inherits from `prog-mode` and some that don't (like `rust-mode`, IIRC). So I'd rather not depend on whether the major mode implemented that or not.

Answer (score 0):

Well, since I already had a tool that went most of the way (my current `enter-key-dwim`) and emacs already has a tool that did what I want, I sidestepped the philosophical question and did the pragmatic thing; I replaced "newline and indenting" with "newline and indenting also with special behavior if inside a comment" (`indent-new-comment-line`).

This is acceptable for me right now. I don't mind having to press `C-j` for a non-comment-newline ... Yet.